# SQL query with additional informations

Tags: sql

I have a RDB with observations of something. So I have a beginTimestamp and a endTimestamp. Now I want all Observations of a special time period + a extra cell with a boolean saying true if it is the first Observation.

My Table Structure looks something like this:

```
ID  | Bird | beginTimestamp | endTimestamp
********************************************
101 | 125  | 3.4.2014 12:30 | 3.4.2014 12:33 //first Observation of this bird
102 | 125  | 3.4.2014 14:15 | 3.4.2014 14:27 //second Observation of this bird
103 | 126  | 3.4.2014 12:31 | 3.4.2014 12:45 //5th Observation of this bird
```

So now I want to know how many new and 'knwon' Birds where there in the time period of: 3.4.2014 12:31 - 3.4.2014 12:32

in this case 1 new and 1 'known' .

Is something like this possible and how?

Comment: What do you mean by a special time period? Can you show us your DB/table structure please?

Comment: So 'known' is an ID with duplicate records?

Comment: No sry I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example for SQL Server:

```
 SELECT O.Bird, O.beginTimestamp, O.endTimestamp,
        CASE
            WHEN FS.firstSeenTimestamp = O.beginTimestamp THEN 'True'
            ELSE 'False'
        END AS IsFirstTimeSeen
   FROM Observations AS O
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        -- Identify first instance of each bird being seen
         SELECT Bird, MIN(beginTimestamp) AS firstSeenTimestamp
           FROM Observations
          GROUP BY Bird
        ) AS FS
        ON FS.Bird = O.Bird
```

We identify the first time a "known" bird has been seen inside of the LEFT JOIN, and we use a CASE statement to append the additional column indicating if it's the first time it was seen.

I've used 'True' and 'False' for ease of reading, but typically I'd use 1 and 0 to indicate True and False respectively.

-= Edit =-

Following the update to the question, you can use the following to get a count per bird in a specified date range:

```
DECLARE @RangeStart DATETIME
DECLARE @RangeEnd DATETIME
SET @RangeStart = '2014-04-03T00:00:00'
SET @RangeEnd = '2014-04-03T23:59:59'

 SELECT O.Bird,
        SUM (CASE
            WHEN O.beginTimestamp = FS.firstSeenTimestamp THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS CountOfFirstSeen,
        SUM (CASE
            WHEN O.beginTimestamp > FS.firstSeenTimestamp THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS CountOfSeenAgain
   FROM Observations AS O
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        -- Identify first instance of each bird being seen
         SELECT Bird, MIN(beginTimestamp) AS firstSeenTimestamp
           FROM Observations
          GROUP BY Bird
        ) AS FS
        ON FS.Bird = O.Bird
  WHERE O.beginTimestamp BETWEEN @RangeStart AND @RangeEnd
  GROUP BY O.Bird
```

Comment: At first thank you very much for this answer. At first I thought I count the new and the knwon in Java but with your Query I think I can also count the 1s and 0s in the SQL Query to get the result right in SQL syntax.

Comment: So I think I have all in this fiddle with a schema like @AK47s fiddle and your query: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b52e/3/0). Can you please implement the count function I mentioned in the comment before if possible, because I think I'm to silly for this after a hour of trying. And do you maybe know if this is possible with a embedded Derby DB?

Comment: If you add the expected outcome you will get a more accurate answer.  I modified my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47548/4/0)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this LOGIC, for clear picture ,please check **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35daa/1)**

```
select a.*, 'Observation no ' + Cast(oldRecs.beforThis as Varchar(10))  + ' for this bird'  from joborder as a
outer apply
    (
        select COUNT(jo_no) + 1 as beforThis from joborder as b
        where b.jo_no < a.jo_no
            and b.jo_status = a.jo_status
    )as oldRecs
```